# Error al insertar datos en la base de datos desde el formulario

Tags: php, javascript, html

Hola amigos una pregunta alguien sabe porque no me están insertando los datos en la base de datos muchas gracias :(

```
$('#btncreartipovehiculo').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        carguePlacas = $('#carguePlacas').val();
        placa = $('#placa').val();


        if(carguePlacas == '' || placa == ''){
            alert('Debe digitar los datos del técnico.');
        }
        else{
            var datosTecnico = {
                carguePlacas : $('#tipo_vehiculo').val(),
                placa       : $('#placa').val()

            };
            $.post('php/agregarplaca.php', datosTecnico, function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                if (data == 0){
                    alert('No se pudo procesar. Intente mas tarde.');
                    return;
                }
                if (data == 2){
                    alert('No se ha ingresado contrato a la inspeccion.');
                    return;
                }
                if (data == 3){
                    alert('No se pudo procesar. Error al insertar.');
                    return;
                }
                if (data > 10){
                    alert('Se ha guardado correctamente el id_tecnico: ' + data);
                    return;
                }
                alert('Error:' + data);


            });
        }

    });
```

ESTE ES MI JAVASCRIPT

ESTE ES MI HTML

```
<select   id="carguePlacas">

                <option value="tipo_vehiculo">placa grua</option>
                <option value="tipo_vehiculo">placa canasta</option>
                <option value="tipo_vehiculo">placa moto</option>
                  <option value="tipo_vehiculo">placa vehiculo</option>                 
          </select>
          <em></em>
  <input type="text" id="placa" style="display:none;">
  <input type="submit" value="Subir placa" id="btncreartipovehiculo" />


  </div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
$("#carguePlacas").change(function(){//evento on chage para capturar el valor seleccionado

   var transporte=$(this).val();//obtener valor de el slect 

   $("#placa").css("display","block").focus().attr("placeholder","placa aqui");

   $("em").html("Escribe la placa  "+"<b>"+ transporte +"<b/>");

})
</script>

<?php
include('php/mostrarplaca.php');
?>
```

ESTE ES MI PHP

//

```
<?php
session_start();
include "conectar.php";
$carguePlacas       = addslashes($_POST['carguePlacas']);
$placa      = addslashes($_POST['placa']);


if (!empty($_POST)){ 
        if ($_SESSION['id_inspeccion'] == null or $_SESSION['id_inspeccion'] == ''){ 
            echo 2; //No se tiene variable id_contrato
        }
        else {
            //echo 1;
            $sql =   "INSERT INTO vehiculo_inspeccion (carguePlacas , placa , id_inspeccion) 
                            VALUES ( '" . $carguePlacas . "',  '" . $placa . "',". $_SESSION['id_inspeccion'] .")";
            $con = Conectar();

            $con->query(utf8_decode($sql));

            if ( $con->affected_rows > 0){
                $nuevoId = $con->insert_id;
                echo $nuevoId;
            } 
            else{
                echo 3;
            }
        }
}
else{ 
    echo 0;
}
?>
```

Comment: que error te da? o siempre pasa por el `if ($_SESSION['id_inspeccion'] == null` ?

Comment: Amigo no me sale ni el alert el problema creo que va desde javascript que ni lo coje ($_SESSION['id_inspeccion'] es el formulario el cual se genera de una inspeccion

Comment: Ok no te da el alert porque en el js tiene que indicarle que es un string, es decir cuando dices `echo 2` en el php el devuelve al js un string y en el js lo estas comparando como número, coloca en el js `data == "2"` ó convierte data en número asi: `parseInt(data) == 2`

Comment: tampoco me salio el alert amigo :'c

Comment: antes de cualquiera de los `if` coloca un `console.log(data)` y dime que te sale por favor, lo ves por la consola del navegador en la pestaña `console`

Comment: asi amigo verdad if (console.log(data)){
     alert('No se pudo procesar. Intente mas tarde.');
     return;
    }
    if (console.log(data)){
     alert('No se ha ingresado contrato a la inspeccion.');
     return;
    }
    if (console.log(data)){
     alert('No se pudo procesar. Error al insertar.');
     return;
    }
    if (console.log(data)){
     alert('Se ha guardado correctamente el id_tecnico: ' + data);
     return;
    }
    alert('Error:' + data);

Comment: no, colocalo asi `$.post('php/agregarplaca.php', datosTecnico, function(data, textStatus, xhr) {` y luego colocas `console.log(data)` y despues lo demas como lo tienes ahi lo que te indica es que imprima por consola el valor de `data` antes de evaluar cualquier `if` que ya tienes osea antes del `if (data == 0){` y me dices que te sale

Comment: no me salio nada en consola amigo :'(

Comment: Ok fijate en la consola del navegador cuando haces la peticion fijate en la respuesta dentro de esa peticion a ver que te sale, seguro te esta dando un error en PHP

Comment: no amigo no me salio ni un error :( en consola

Comment: Tienes habilitado tu módulo de PHP para que muestre todos los errores?

Comment: creo que si jeje :c

Comment: Ok trata de colocar tu $.post asi `$.post('php/agregarplaca.php', datosTecnico)
    .done(function(data){  Aqui colocas tus if })
    .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
        aqui colocas un console.log(error) o un alert a ver que te dice
    });` trata de acomodar tu $.post para que capture el error en la función fail con un console.log o un alert de error y me dices que te sale

Comment: mira amigo estos son mis campos de mi base de datos
id_veh_ins
tipo_vehiculo
placa
id_inspeccion

Comment: amigo tienes correo y te comparto mi pantalla porfa

Comment: En mi perfil tienes toda mi info

Comment: vale amigo gracias ya te pude escribir en el gmail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema lo tienes que el evento click nunca lo incluyes en tu html para ser invocado, tu codigo deberia de quedar asi:

```
   <select   id="carguePlacas">
     <option value="tipo_vehiculo">placa grua</option>
     <option value="tipo_vehiculo">placa canasta</option>
     <option value="tipo_vehiculo">placa moto</option>
     <option value="tipo_vehiculo">placa vehiculo</option>                 
   </select>
   <em></em>
   <input type="text" id="placa" style="display:none;">
   <input type="submit" value="Subir placa" id="btncreartipovehiculo" />
 </div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#carguePlacas").change(function(){//evento on chage para capturar el valor seleccionado

      var transporte=$(this).val();//obtener valor de el slect 
      $("#placa").css("display","block").focus().attr("placeholder","placa aqui");

      $("em").html("Escribe la placa  "+"<b>"+ transporte +"<b/>");

    $('#btncreartipovehiculo').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        carguePlacas = $('#carguePlacas').val();
        placa = $('#placa').val();

        if(carguePlacas == '' || placa == ''){
            alert('Debe digitar los datos del técnico.');
        }
        else{
            var datosTecnico = {
                carguePlacas : $('#tipo_vehiculo').val(),
                placa       : $('#placa').val()

            };
            $.post('php/agregarplaca.php', datosTecnico, function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                if (data == 0){
                    alert('No se pudo procesar. Intente mas tarde.');
                    return;
                }
                if (data == 2){
                    alert('No se ha ingresado contrato a la inspeccion.');
                    return;
                }
                if (data == 3){
                    alert('No se pudo procesar. Error al insertar.');
                    return;
                }
                if (data > 10){
                    alert('Se ha guardado correctamente el id_tecnico: ' + data);
                    return;
                }
                alert('Error:' + data);


            });
        }

    });

    })
    </script>

    <?php
    include('php/mostrarplaca.php');
    ?>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo Post resuelto te agradezco un resto